# Can I use weapons and old abilities when True Polymorphed into an ancient brass dragon and then using Change Shape to turn back to humanoid?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, shapeshifting

If I am permanently turned into an [ancient brass dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-brass-dragon) with [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) and then use the Change Shape trait to become a humanoid again, can I buy new weapons and use them? Can I use my class abilities and my spells like before?

Comment: Related: [Can you use a Dragon's Change Shape Ability to Turn Back Into Yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64808/can-you-use-a-dragons-change-shape-ability-to-turn-back-into-yourself) (you seem to assume the answer is yes), [Can I true polymorph into an Ancient Brass Dragon, and then use its Change Shape ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115349/can-i-true-polymorph-into-an-ancient-brass-dragon-and-then-use-its-change-shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mostly no

Change Shape states that:

> In a new form, the dragon retains its alignment, hit points, Hit Dice, ability to speak, 
>   **proficiencies**, Legendary Resistance, lair actions, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores, as well as this action. **Its statistics and capabilities are otherwise replaced by those of the new form, except any class features** or legendary actions of that form.

You keep the proficiencies of the dragon. You gain all other statistics not listed except class features.

### Can I can buy new weapons and use them?

You can buy new weapons and use them, but you will not have proficiency in them since a dragon doesn't have weapon proficiencies.

### Can I use my class abilities and my spells like before?

Unfortunately class abilities, spells known, and spellcasting are all class features, so you won't be able to use them.

Comment: For what it's worth, it is not guaranteed that dragons have no weapon proficiencies (see [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107869/41726)), and I know of at least one [dragon that uses weapons in an altered form](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/creatures#IymriththeDragon) in an adventure module.

Comment: Ancient brass dragons don't wield any weapons, and Iymrith is 1 dragon.