# What happens when I am True Polymorphed but the monster doesn't have any game statistics to replace mine?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, attributes

The *[true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* spell description states that the target's game statistics are replaced with those of the new form. When I *true polymorph* into a monster such as [archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/archmage), or shadow assassin, without a specific class or race, do I keep mine?

Comment: Archmages are a specific race, but can be any race.  The caster of true polymorph would choose what race you become.

Comment: I was moreso addressing a bad example than giving an answer to the main question.

Comment: I believe the OP was using Archmage as an example and not the question. The OP originally had Shadow Assassin listed.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That is probably the case. I like this question and it is good as a general reference for this instead of a specific for one monster (archmage).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It is in dungeon of the mad mage.pg. 316

Comment: Related: [Does a caster under the effect of a True Polymorph spell retain their class levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62043/does-a-caster-under-the-effect-of-a-true-polymorph-spell-retain-their-class-leve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Race

Humanoid NPCs/monsters usually have a tag appended to their humanoid creature type, which designates their race. An [archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/archmage) is a humanoid, but its tag states that it can be any race. If you *[true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* into an archmage, you can keep your original race, or you can choose any other humanoid race (the caster chooses, if you didn't cast the spell yourself).

If you *true polymorph* into a shadow assassin (from *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*), your creature type is undead, and your have no specified race.

In any case, you wouldn't carry over any PC racial traits that aren't specified in the new form's stats.

### Class

Normally only PCs have a class. Although the *Dungeon Master's Guide* provides a method for DMs to create NPCs with PC classes, there are no published monster/NPC stat blocks that include a PC class. If you *[true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* into an [archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/archmage) or shadow assassin, you'll no longer have a PC class. You wouldn't carry over any PC class features that aren't specified in the new form's stats.

Answer (score 3):

*[True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* says:

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the new form. It retains its alignment and personality.

What it means is "Put the character sheet aside and use the statblock of the new creature chosen". Literally everything is replaced. The original character is almost completely irrelevant to the polymorphed replacement, nothing carries over except for alignment and personality as indicated in the quote.

As far as race for humanoid creatures goes, that's covered in the Appendix B of the *Monster Manual*, under [Customizing NPCs](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/nonplayer-characters):

> **Racial Traits.** You can add racial traits to an NPC. For example, a halfling druid might have a speed of 25 feet and the Lucky trait. Adding racial traits to an NPC doesn’t alter its challenge rating. For more on racial traits, see the *Player’s Handbook*.

If you want to modify an "Any Race" NPC to be a particular race, you consult the PHB and make the same adjustments you would to a player character.

Comment: The _Monster Manual_ quote is addressing DMs who are placing NPCs in their games. A player whose character casts _true polymorph_ isn't free to drop racial traits onto the new form, unless of course the DM goes along.

Comment: @mdrichey And there are those of us that hold that the NPC section is nothing more than templates for a race, I personally do not allow transmutations into professions which are what I belief are the intent of the NPC section. But I am likely unique in that perspective.

Comment: @Slagmoth You're not unique, but the question already indicates that section is on the table, and I decided not to challenge that parameter.

Answer (score -4):

Archmages can be of any race. The caster of true Polymorph would choose what race you become.

> Archmage
>   *Medium humanoid (any race), any alignment*
>   Armor Class 12 (15 with mage armor)
>   Hit Points 99 (18d8 + 18)
>   Speed 30 ft.  (etc) (SRD, p. 395)

Since it is any race, the option is open to select one.

If the spell caster True Polymorphed your PC into a Drow, then the race is as specified in the stat block

> Elf, Drow
>   *Medium humanoid (elf), neutral evil*
>   Armor Class 15
>   (chain shirt)
>   Hit Points 13 (3d8)
>   Speed 30 ft.

Comment: Just curious, did you do this because of KorvinStarmast's comment? Although it will appear in your inbox (because it's a comment on your post), that comment of KorvinStarmast's was intended for JRodge01. I just don't want you to think that KorvinStarmast was telling you what to do, because that definitely wasn't anyone's intentions. It was just a suggestion to JRodge01.

Comment: @NathanS You are correct, but I confess to having chuckled at the sequence of events.

Comment: Looks like the asker copied someone else's comment into an answer. I think this should be deleted and the commenter should be allowed to post it as an answer himself if they want.

Comment: @mdrichey Completely agree, just wanted to make sure the asker knew what was going on.

Comment: @JoãoGrando, just so you know, if a comment has @ followed by someone's username, the comment is intended for them, not you, even if it appears in your inbox (obviously, in this case, this comment is for you, because I used your name; comments without names are less obvious and must be judged by context). This answer will probably be deleted, but no hard feelings.

Comment: @NathanS I edited in some support for the self answer. :)