# Does Primal Strike work with Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, polymorph

Amazingly, I can't find anything even close to definitive on this across multiple google searches and phrasings.

A Circle of the Moon druid casts polymorph on themselves for some of that sweet, sweet, Giant Ape combat action.  Does the Primal Strike class feature still function?  Exact wording from the PHB (dunno if there's errata about this) says this:

> Starting at 6th level, your attacks in beast form count as magical for the [blah blah blah]..."

It doesn't specify **"While Wild Shaped..."** or anything similar, and as mentioned, I haven't been able to find even a similar topic discussing their intersection.

Comment: Good question, but it's a possible duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57717/can-a-polymorphed-creature-use-class-features-that-dont-require-speech-or-hand). I think it's worth asking independently, so that we can clarify both that no class features function while Polymorphed at all, and that this applies to class features designed to function while in Wild Shape.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme I don't think it's a dupe. In this case DeadRose is asking if 'beast form' counts for Polymorph or just Wild Shape.

Comment: @NautArch I agree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, *polymorph* replaces all class features including *primal strike*

The description for *polymorph* says:

> The target's game Statistics, including mental Ability Scores, are replaced by the Statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality.

So literally everything about your character is replaced by the statistics of the creature you polymorphed into (except alignment and personality). Class features are included in that.

Essentially, when you are polymorphed, you completely put away your character sheet and you use only what you see in the creature's stat block. If you don't see it in the stat block you cannot use it.

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/905513072898531330) has confirmed this as well:

> Polymorph replaces your game statistics, including class features, with those of the beast. [...]

**Thus, since *primal strike* is a class feature, you cannot use it while polymorphed.**

Comment: This is perfect. The dev quote pretty much exactly answers my question, even if it was for another class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

## RAW it wouldn't work.

Polymorph replaces the in game statistics of the character with the in game statistics of the polymorphed creature:

> The target's game Statistics, including mental Ability Scores, are
> replaced by the Statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its
> alignment and personality.

And then it further specifies:

> The creature is limited in the actions it can perform by the nature
> of its new form, and it can't speak, cast Spells, or take any other
> action that requires hands or Speech.

I would rule that the creature isn't a druid, and isn't capable of using a Druid's class features.