# Who was the wizard that polymorphed himself into an Otter?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore

I vaguely remember a question being answered citing that some wizard or another had polymorphed or true polymorphed himself into an otter, and because he liked it so much that he used a wish to make it permanent.

Can anyone cite the source?  Is it from an actual game manual or from one of the D&D novels?  By any chance did he start any otter families whilst in this form?

This has indirect relevance to another question I asked a week back.

I will also accept any answers or lists of rule book sources of notable wizards who have permanently polymorphed themselves into various creatures / creatures of note.

Comment: Related, near dupe: [What are the circumstances of Traxigor's transformation and do they explain how he retained his magical abilities as an otter?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181139/62294)

Comment: Note that, as the now-linked duplicate says, he did **not** polymorph _himself_ into an otter.  He _may_ have been the author of the wish spell that made his transformation permanent, but we don't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Traxigor

You'll find him in *Baldur’s Gate: Descent into Avernus*, their [wiki entry](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Traxigor), or on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/424613-traxigor) where he's readily findable as the highest CR beast (though as an individual, named thankfully not a valid form for *polymorph* etc.).

Comment: Is this the guy in question?  https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Traxigor

Comment: @PlayPatrice Sure is, added the link

Comment: By any chance does it mention if Traxigor had any children in said otter form? (I do not own this game material)  I'm trying to research published precedence on "polymorphic" breeding results....

Comment: @PlayPatrice Nope. I already investigated Traxigor when you asked that question, nothing helpful is to be found about him.

Comment: Re: "though as an individual, named thankfully not a valid form for _polymorph_ etc.": [citation needed].  _Cf._ [Can you permanently True Polymorph into yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64578/23547)